# php, simulate include? Cache system

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to create a small template system and have a function that loops over an array of items.
Currently I'm using the output buffering functions and include so i can load up the template file while it has scope to the class.

```
function loadTemplate($name, $vars) {
    $buf = '';
    $path = $name . '.html';
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $this->vars = $vars;
        ob_start();
        include($path);
        $buf = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $buf;
}
```

I was just wondering if I could store the initial template in an array then have it run (As if it was included) while keeping scope, like.

```
function loadTemplate($name, $vars) {
    $buf = $template = '';
    if (isset($this->cache[$name]))
        $template = $this->cache[$name];
    else {
        $path = $name . '.html';
        $template = file_get_contents($path);
        $this->cache[$name] = $template;
    }
    //Exec template here with scope.
}
```

Or am i just being pedantic and trying to micro optimize :)

Comment: Templating systems are redundant in PHP. PHP itself is a template engine, why do you want to add more overhead to it?

Comment: Possibly because PHP is quite a complex template language and usually php template code looks horrible compared to cleaner template systems. Many webdesigners in the company i work for simply don't manage to work with PHP very good. Also `<? ?>` tend to confuse syntax highlighting if used like this `<option value="<?= $link ?>" <?= ($selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>`. At last, don't forget: Templates can be reused by other languages, PHP not (at least not that good).

Comment: I'm just trying to separate content from code so updates can be applied without effecting user customisations.

Comment: @dbemerlin Yeah, using an actual templating system will (most of the time) make the code look cleaner. It's just my preference, I prefer using MVC and having the View in straight PHP.

Comment: @Alex Check out the MVC pattern (and MVC frameworks such as CakePHP)

Comment: @dbemerlin: What programs are you using that get tripped up on inline PHP?  Every one that I've used recognizes it quite fine...  And there's a big difference between using a templating engine (like Smarty) and using separate template files where the bulk of the HTML is in its own file (Some framework call these views, others call them layouts, etc)...  I'm against templating engines, but I actually encourage template files (since they encourage the segregation of logic from display)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be looking into CakePHP as per NullUserException's comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If i were you and had complex operations in the template files I would save them to filesystem. I've modified your function, I think you'll understand what happens there:

```
<?php

function template($name, $vars = array())
{
    $cache = 'cache/'; // Path to cache folder, must be writeable
    $expire = 3600 * 3; // Cache lifetime, 3 hours
    $path = $name . '.html';
    $cache_file = $cache . sha1($path) . '.txt'; // Generate cache file path and hash-name

    // If cache file exists and it hasn't expired yet we must get cached data
    if (file_exists($cache_file) && filemtime($cache_file) > (time() - $expire))
    {
        return unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));
    }

    // Return NULL if template file doesn't exist
    if (!file_exists($path))
    {
        return null;
    }

    $this->vars = $vars;

    ob_start();
    include_once $path;
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    // Save output to the cache file
    file_put_contents($cache_file, serialize($output));

    return $output;
}

?>
```

P.S. Haven't tested the function.

Comment: My main thought was to try and reduce the amount of disk reading but i think it would just over complicate for little performance gains.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will do what's necessary...  The issue is that (from what I'm gathering) the output of the file will change dependent upon `$vars`.  So you'd at least need to adjust your cache file definition to be dependent upon that array.  Which will likely kill your cache hit rate if anything changes temporally (or at least result in a ton of cache files for each "template" file)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it makes much difference if you include an template once again, as you said yourself... it would be micro optimizing.
But, what you could do is to save the already included templates source to an array and use the template name as the key for the array.
When you run your loadTemplate function, you can just do a `array_key_exists` to see if it is included already.

But if I may, I would recommend the [smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net). I used it in my projects and find it just perfect. I have adapted it a bit to run smoother with my code, but now it really is perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep including it.  The only alternative would be to read the contents then eval them, and that's going to be worse.  The overhead of the second include should be significantly less since the page is already parsed into opcode...

Answer (score 0):

That's most useless cache you can implement.
You'd better think of HTTP conditional get implementation which will make no need to call temlpate at all. And then go for opcode cache which will cache your includes automatically.

But at firs you have to profile your app/templater to see if you need any cache at all